# How to generate a score between 0-100 based on the input dataset given to the ML model

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am working on a problem where I have to generate a score between 0-100 as output. I have data about customers who we want to sell a product to. We want to score based on the likely ness of the customer buying the product. How can I approach this? I used a random-forest regressor I am getting 1.0 as the output when I try to find its accuracy.

Comment: You get 1.0 as the output of the model or as the accuracy?

Comment: as accuracy, I am getting 1.0

Comment: Accuracy is a metric for classification problems, not for regression problems like yours.